# How do I store new client information in array and be able to view it again in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, user-input

This is my assignment. 
I have to create an application that show a menu and perform the corresponding action based on the user's choice. Here is what my menu should include

```
1. add a new client - keep it as the current client
2. find a client with a given name - keep it as the current client
3. add a service for the current client
4. print the current client's balance
5. print the current client's history of services
6. print all the clients' balances
7. exit [save all the data to a file option and retrieve it back when the program starts]
```

```
System.out.println("Welcome to Tracy'S Auto Mechanic Shop!");
do{
System.out.println("\nTracy's Auto Mechanic Shop Main Menu");
System.out.println("------------------------------------");
for(int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
System.out.println((i < choices.length-1? ? i+1 : 0) + ". " + choices[i]);
}

System.it.print("Make your choice: ");
choice = input.nextInt();

switch(choice){
case 1:
main_addNewClient();
break;
case 2:
main_SearchClient();
break;
case 3:
main_AddService();
break;
case 4:
main_ViewBalance();
break;
case 5:
main_ViewHistory();
break;
case 6:
main_ViewAll();
break;
case 0: 
System.exit(0);
default:
System.out.println("Invalid choice. Try again.");
}
}while(choice != 0);

input.close();
}
```

So far I have created the menu but I am stuck at adding a new client. How do I store all information into an array and save it? I created a class as shown at the bottom:

```
class Client{
   public String name;
   public String email;
   public String make;
   public int year;
   public String vin;

   public static void Client(String name, String email, String make, int year, String vin){
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
      this.make = make;
      this.year = year; 
      this.vin = vin;

   }

}
```

For the option of adding a new client, I created a method in main

```
public static void main_addNewClient() {
String name, email, vin, make;
int year;
input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
name = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter your email: ");
email = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter vin: ");
vin = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter make: ");
make = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter year: ");
year = input.nextLine();
```

but how do I take all the user input and store it into an array? I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Either use a `List<Client>` (and search through it to find existing clients) or a `Map<String,Client>` (which lets you ask for a specific client by key).

Answer (score 0):

First, declare an ArrayList in your main which will contain all the clients

```
 ArrayList clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
```

Second, create a new **client** object within your method and fill with the data you get from the input then add this client data to the ArrayList you have created

```
   Client client = new Client(name,email,vin,year,make);
   clients.add(client);
```

Comment: I don't think its Android specific. Looks like just a regular Java exercise from college/school.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise {

// list to store your clients
static List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

static class Client{
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String make;
    public int year;
    public String vin;

    Client(String name, String email, String make, int year, String vin){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.make = make;
        this.year = year;
        this.vin = vin;
    }
}

public static void main_addNewClient() {
    String name, email, vin, make;
    int year;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your email: ");
    email = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter vin: ");
    vin = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter make: ");
    make = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter year: ");
    year = input.nextInt();

    // create new client object with input you got
    Client c = new Client(name, email, make, year, vin);
    // add client to the list
    clients.add(c);
}
}
```

Is that what you wanted to know? There is lots into this exercise. I think you first need to build a menu which will ask a user what he wants to do: add new client, find a client, etc.

Comment: Yes i already built the menu (I've added it into the post). Its just storing client's basic info that I was having trouble with.